# How to import yml file into MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, sql, import, phpmyadmin, yaml

I just looked for every option in my `PHPMyAdmin`. But just can't find any thing that kinda works for. I got this databasefile from a company for freelance work. I said to them it will be fine i can do it. But 2 days later is still haven't found anything that could work for me. Is there someone who can look for me why i can't import any `yml`files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpMyAdmin can create YAML as an export/dump format, but can't import them. Can you get the file as an SQL format, which is a more standard interchange format anyway?

You can verify this in two ways; looking in `libraries/plugins/import` I don't see YAML listed, or going to the Import tab within phpMyAdmin you can see the available types from the "Format" dropdown; YAML isn't listed there, either.