# Docker-compose on Windows 7: how to import a db dump when using a yaml file?

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I'm started from here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

I got this running well on my windows 7

```
version: '2'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "mysql_root_password"
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
     - 8080:80
    volumes:
     - /sessions
volumes:
    db_data:
```

**My question is: how can I import a db-dump from a Windows Machime?** 
My goal is to work locally on a dump of the production (I've already have the dump in the same folder of my docker-compose.yaml file).

Comment: Slow down!!! You're talking about import a dump when container is started and then you jump into phpMyAdmin? I am not following you, you should read once again your post and try to write it better, I believe you're mixing two things here. Did you tried to `bash` into the MySQL container and use the command line for see if the database was created and the data loaded?

Comment: I never tried this before but as the author said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28934504/719427) phpMyAdmin can export/dump into YAML but can't import them so I would recommend to export as standar SQL file and avoid extra headaches ....

Comment: Did you fix the issue? Either answer here works for you? If so then please accept one of them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `bash` into the MySQL container and the DB was created and the data imported then your first issue is fix.

Regarding the second one `I'm not able to login from within phpMyAdmin` and because I am not seeing the service listed on your `docker-compose.yml` I would recommend to install and configure it following the docs at [phpmyadmin](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/). Very important read the ENV variables [here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker#environment-variables-summary) since you need to setup them in order to allow the phpMyAdmin container read/write from/to the MySQL container.

Ex (from [here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)):

```
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
     - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    restart: always
    ports:
     - 8080:80
    volumes:
     - /sessions
```

You're missing this part on your Dockerfile or maybe you don't get just yet how Docker works at all which lead me to recommend you to read a bit about it.

**UPDATE**

Since the answer is non longer related to phpMyAdmin and now turns into `docker volumes` under Windows here is the updated answer.

Mount volumes on Windows work as in Linux, ex:

```
php-fpm:
    build: docker/php-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./sources:/data/www
```

The service definition above will work on both OS, you can try it [here](https://github.com/reypm/symfony3app/tree/httpd). I am using latest Docker for Windows (the Beta tagged as RCXX)

Now a workaround for your case could be either mount a host volume where you have the `.sql` dump file or use the `COPY` command from Docker to move the file inside the container and then use `RUN` or a bash script to import it back to the DB.

Comment: So .... what do you need now? You've change your answer several times on the last few minutes making us to answer incorrectly ....

Comment: The problem is still the main question: how to import the dump file  using yaml under windows. I removed extra useless material from my question. Sorry a lot for confusion

Comment: @realtebo did you read my latest comment where I said phpMyAdmin can export to YAML but can't import? I never ever had imported a YAML file in a DB not only MySQL but PostgreSQL as well. You'll need to find a way to transform this YAML into a SQL or export directly into SQL using phpMyAdmin

Comment: I exported my actual db using phpmyadmin into a `.sql` file. I'd like to use to my sql file as mount point, as suggested into threeve's answer, but under Windows it needs some kind of trick because using path (absolute or relative) will not works

Comment: There is not trick, it should work same way, you have something wrong around, if so please update the OP and add your full Dockerfile and `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 3):

One way that you can do this is to mount a folder with the dump into the directory `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` when using the official mysql image.

This is a pretty good solution for working in a team, where everyone should be working off the same base db.  You can read more about that in the [documentation.](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)  This will only occur on the first run of the container.  If you delete the container, it will do a fresh import.  This has it's uses as well.

More often, I do as some of the other answers suggest:

```
docker-compose exec db mysql -u root -p DB_NAME < DUMP_FILE_IN_CONTAINER
```

It's important to note, that you *still* need to mount the dump file in the container!  It will not work for a file on the host machine!

You don't necessarily need to mount an entire folder (though you can - all scripts in the above-mentioned folder will execute in alphabetical order).  You can just mount your dump file like this:

```
services:
  db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  volumes:
    - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./path/to/dump/on/host.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/anyname.sql
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
    MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
    MYSQL_USER: wordpress
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

Comment: Please: tell me exactly how to mount a folder under windows? Your example is working on linux, but on windows ... how to do?

Comment: If you use a relative path it should work the same.  Updated example.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It complain about bad chars in the path (and i'm tried using simply `./dump/host.sql` as host path. This is because on windows 7 all is running through virtual box VM and docks command line itself is a MINGW64. So I need a Docker+Windows expert